# How to scrape video live stream with Python

Tags: python, iframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I have been working with Scrapy and BeautifulSoup to scrape websites for video links which I can then use within my application that works quite well. However, now I thought i should challenge myself and I am now trying to scrape a live stream. I cant seem to get a proper video link for live streams.

I was looking at the network tab which looks as [follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j58eY.png):

is there anyway to download all the m3u8 files to my device and then play them seemlessly like im watching the stream on my app? Or is there an even better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: If only you provided a link then I could test for it otherwise, I am not sure. Although, if its on the networks tab, then I am convinced scrapy playwright can grab all the information that you need and save it as a file.